# Wp-e-Commerce Multi Currency Magic in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on an e-commerce website. I added a plugin called "Wp-e-Commerce Multi Currency Magic".

It works well. It changes all the product rate according to selected currency on button click. And that's the problem: I want it to change when I select a currency in select box without any button clicks, just on change event.

So is it possible to modify this plugin like that? If you have any idea regarding my problem please help me out, I'd greatly appreciate  your answer. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code or at least a link to your plugin, where we can test it.

Comment: **This is the link where you can can test this plugin..** [link](http://.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce-multi-currency-magic/)

Comment: ... or maybe [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce-multi-currency-magic/) ;)

Comment: oops i ate up link.. your link of that plugin is the one in which i need to customize. so now do you have any idea to customize it like what i described in my problem..? :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I only tried to help you make your question clearer, but I can't help you with WordPress :( Hope someone else could!

Answer (score 1):

I coded a plugin to convert currencies of all price fields in wp e-commerce live in a bubble tooltip just a few days ago.

Here is a demo http://haet.at/wp-e-commerce-currency-helper/

You can install the plugin in the wordpress plugin repository, it's free.
I hope you can give me some feedback.